# how to run formula for a range (like a loop) and sum the results?

Tags: google-sheets, sum

In `google sheets`, I am using a formula like this:

```
=SUM(
    VLOOKUP(D2,I2:J8,2,FALSE) * E2, 
    VLOOKUP(D3,I2:J8,2,FALSE) * E3, 
    VLOOKUP(D4,I2:J8,2,FALSE) * E4, 
    VLOOKUP(D5,I2:J8,2,FALSE) * E5, 
    VLOOKUP(D6,I2:J8,2,FALSE) * E6
)
```

How to write it as a range? like

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(x,I2:J8,2,FALSE) * y)
x is D2 to D6
y is E2 to E6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=arrayformula(SUM(VLOOKUP(D2:D6,I2:J8,2,FALSE)*E2:E6))
```